# How to have data in Range column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 1 table named Temp1 and Columns are as below. In this table we have to make sure that salary of employee for any designation must be in between TopRange and Bottom Range. So I need to create a column combining 2 column Salary Top Range and Salary Bottom range

```
Emp ID  (primary key)
Emp Name
Designation
Salary 
Salary top range 
salary bottom range
```

Sample data:

```
Emp ID  -123,
Emp Name  - ABC,
Designation  - Executive,
Salary -10000,
Salary top range - 15000,
Salary bottom Range - 3000
```

I want to create a column `Range` with a value of `3000-15000`. Is that possible in SQL Server?

Comment: What's the benefit of such a column? Since you cannot have multiple values in a column - you'll have to convert the numerical values for bottom and top end of the range into **strings** to concat them together - and that'll only make it that much harder to actually do the check to see if the actual salary is in the defined range. I don't see any benefit - but a number of drawbacks - from squeezing that together into one column......

Comment: hmm thank you but the requirement is just to showcase this data we need range column because dashboard will directly import data from SQl as per coding and will display  in same format. otherwise for acutal comparison it will use seperate column only @marc_s

Comment: You don't want another column. Just `concat` it when you select, like this: `concat(cast(SalaryBottom as varchar(10)), ' - ', cast(SalaryTop as varchar(10)))`. You could put it into a view, a computed column or a user-defined function if you really want

Comment: Seems like range depends on designation? If so, you should move that information into another table so that you don't repeat it (inconsistently most likely) for each unique value of designation. That would require a foreign key to this new table.

Comment: @marc_s: *"What's the benefit of such a column? Since you cannot have multiple values in a column . . . "* The issue isn't multiple values; the issue is *complex* values. Data types can arbitrarily complex, but the dbms must treat such a type as if it cannot be decomposed, or the dbms has to supply functions to operate on it.  For example, [PostgreSQL has a native Range data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and functions that operate on it. T-SQL doesn't support Range data types, but it *does* support geometry: points, compound curves, polygons, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a computed column:

```
alter table t add column salary_range as
     ( concat(bottom, '-', top) );
```

This column will be calculated when you query it, so it will always be up-to-date.

Note that `range` is a SQL keyword, so I renamed it to `salary_range`.  As a keyword, it is used in defining the window frame for a window function.

Comment: "salary_range" is just a better name, anyway.